# Why can't I use a specific activity in my intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

It shows error while using the PhoneNumbeActivity. Its my first time using intent after updating it to Android Studio 4.1.2.

```
package com.example.whatsapp;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.telephony.PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher;
    import android.view.View;
    
    import com.example.whatsapp.databinding.ActivityPhoneNumberBinding;
    
    public class PhoneNumber extends AppCompatActivity {
        ActivityPhoneNumberBinding binding;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            binding = ActivityPhoneNumberBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
            setContentView(binding.getRoot());
            binding.continueBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new
    Intent(PhoneNumberActivity.this,OTPActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Replace PhoneNumberActivity.this with PhoneNumber.this

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
 Intent intent = new
    Intent(PhoneNumberActivity.this,OTPActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

With this:

```
 Intent intent = new
    Intent(PhoneNumber.this,OTPActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

As your Activity name is **PhoneNumber**, It doesn't find anything of **PhoneNumberActivity**